# ASM Call instruction cause a stack overflow?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-overflow

This is my ASM function code:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, 8
CALL 00401E20
LEAVE
RETN
```

There's a function at `0x00401E20` which takes no parameters and doesn't return any value. Which is the right way to call a function?

OllyDbg says "Stack overflow" and remarks the 4th line. Sorry, I'm new with ASM, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to **step into** that function to see what's really causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I do that? Please check out my comment below, that's what causes the crash I think.

Comment: Your question seems to be *how to use ollydbg*, and there's a bunch of tutorials for that on the Web. Keep in mind that there's a difference between **step over** and **step into** (shortcut key: F7).

Comment: Yes I think I should read a good tutorial about OllyDbg. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try POP before leaving and returning.

Try this:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, 8

CALL 00401E20

MOV ESP, EBP
POP EBP

LEAVE
RETN
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work :-(. To be more specific, OllyDbg remarks this: `CALL DWORD PTR DS:[1000A000]`. Any other idea?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. The address was wrong, now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a `pop` before you return, `leave` takes care of the epilogue.

Comment: @Gunner Oh yes, that's right. That's what the Wikipedia says. I accepted this answer to be grateful, btw.  :lol Thanks!

Comment: @Gunner always good to know. Anyway, cdonts said he was new to ASM so this is not bad to pop manually to understand the process